# Can not set the path of NDK in project structure in Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-ndk, environment-variables

I am using the latest version of Android studio V4.1 to implement my project on Windows 10.
The project also requires Java 11 and Ndk libraries.

First, I installed NDK V22 and V16 as well as Cmak from SDK tools in SKD manger as shown below:
[image]

Then, Installed Java 11 from Oracel.com, and checked using cmd as shown below:

[image]

I added the paths of SDK and NDK to the local.properties files as follows:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\22.0.7026061
```

Also, added JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_NDK_HOME in the system environment.

The problem is that I can not locate the NDK path from the "File > project structure> Android NDK location" in the Android project to tell the Android studio where is the NDK is located.  It always shows as inactive and can not browse the path as shown in the below picture:

[image]

Info:
Android Gradle Plugin Version 4.1.1

Gradle Version 6.8

Can anyone help to fix this problem?

Comment: Please replace your android tag by an android-studio tag. Maybe you could add an ndk tag.

Comment: Why is this a problem, isn't the path in the form the same as what you set by ```ndk.dir```?

Comment: Yeah, the path is the same. But why I can not browse the NDK location from the project structure window? Do you mean that putting the path as ndk.dir in local.properties is enough and correct?

Comment: Note that you may run into build-time issues if you place the NDK in a path that contains spaces (as yours appear to do).

Comment: I located NDK again into a non-spaced path but still have the same problem.

Comment: Setting `sdk.dir` and `ndk.dir` in `local.properties` file is enough to configure your Android project with SDK and NDK paths. But, `ndk.dir` is deprecated. Now you can to set `sdk.dir` and `android.ndkVersion` properties (E.g: `android.ndkVersion=22.0.7026061`). Or can set NDK version in `build.gradle` file as instructed [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#apply-specific-version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was moved to the build.gradle to keep builds reproducible: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#ndk-path

It's not in the UI because you should almost never use it. You should be using `android.ndkVersion` in almost all cases. `android.ndkPath` (and `ndk.dir`) is just a way to make builds non-reproducible/non-portable.

The cases where `android.ndkPath` makes sense are if your CI service only has the NDK installed to a specific location not known to the SDK, or if you're using an unreleased NDK.